# Powerpivot install fails

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, powerpivot

My machine runs windows 7 professional (64bit) and I use MS office 2010 professional 32 bit.

I'm attempting to (re)install the powerpivot plugin but i get an error stating "installation of powerpivot for excel failed because a higher version already exists on the machine. To proceed, uninstall the higher version and then run powerpivot for excel setup again."

Powerpivot was installed until recently and worked fine. I removed the power pivot plugin using (File | options | manage .com plugins) in an attempt to solve another problem that I had, and now I'm trying to re-install the addin but the error occurs. I already re-installed excel but no help.

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think your install of powerpivot was not completely removed.

check here, notably the registry part:
http://www.uninstallapp.com/article/How-to-uninstall-Microsoft-PowerPivot-for-Excel-2010-Data-Analysis-Expressions-Sample-1.0.html